# How do receptors lose their sensitivity?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, cell-signaling, receptor, insulin

Recently, I learned that one of the causes of Type II diabetes is that insulin receptors on cell surfaces lose their sensitivity due to long-term high exposure to insulin (which occurs as a result of high blood sugar).

How do receptors (like that for insulin) become more resistant to ligands? Is the receptor itself getting damaged? If so, how, and why don't other frequently activated proteins/receptors (like GPCR's) also get damaged? If not, then how does the cell become more "resistant" to insulin?

Comment: There are different mechanisms for different receptors, so this is a very broad question. It's usually a negative feedback from within the cells. For insulin resistance, you can check Figure 1 in [this article](https://diabetes.diabetesjournals.org/content/55/Supplement_2/S9).

Comment: The field of insulin resistance is a very active research area and hundreds of research papers on the topic are published every year. There appear to be many mechanisms involved in the development of insulin resistance and to give a full answer might not be possible at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major celltypes responsible for getting rid of blood glucose are the liver, adipose tissue (fat cells) and the muscles.

The problem of how muscles becomes insulin resistance was solved by a team of scientist led by Gerald Shulman a few years ago.

The mechanism is that incread levels of diglycerides (note that normal fat in the body is in the form of triglycerides) in the muscle  cells prevents/makes it harder for glucose transporters of the type glut-4 to attach to the cell membrane. Thus causing incread levels of insulin in the blood in order to get the muscle cells to accept the glucose.

This seems to be the major reason for how muscle cells become more "resistant" to insulin. It is mostly not the insulin receptors becoming dysfunctional or fewer but diglycerides stopping the insulin receptors from getting the glucose transporters to the cell membrane imparing the glucose uptake. Listen to Geralds Banting price lecture:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnvmEUUtoZw